# Oracle row_number greater than and including 1

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a query that uses the row_number function. I want to return all rows greater than 1 but also include 1.
When I try

```
row_number()over(partition by .. order by)rn
...rn > 1
```

I get rn =  2, 3, 4...

If I do

```
rn >= 1
```

I get rows that only = 1  along with rows greater than 1.

How do I include 1 in rows greater than 1 but not include the rows that are only 1?

All help is greatly appreciated

**Edit**

I was afraid my question wouldn't make sense.
I am searching items in a storage warehouse and trying to find all locations with the same item. My query is a follows

```
select * from (
   select item_number, bin_number, qty
    ,row_number()over(partition by item order by loc) rn --maybe I need count(*) over(....)
     from my_table
) where rn >= 1
```

which returns

```
item_number | bin_number | qty | rn
12345       |  A1        | 2   | 1
123456      |  A2        | 1   | 1
123456      |  A3        | 1   | 2
123456      |  A4        | 4   | 3
```

If change

```
rn > =1
```

to

```
rn > 1
```

I get

```
item_number | bin_number | qty | rn
123456      |  A3        | 1   | 2
123456      |  A4        | 4   | 3
```

I want to include **all** rows when rn is greater than 1

Comment: You should post a test case rather than explaining your requirement only in words.

Comment: Your description seems quite contradictory - you want to include 1 but not include 1... Please explain what you really mean, with sample data and expected results.

Comment: Why not just use the ranking function only for the record which has not duplicate occurrence ??

Comment: You *are* getting all rows when rn is greater than 1. Please edit your request again and show the result you want instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use count instead of row_number.

```
select * from (select count()over(partition by .. order by) cn
                 from ...) x
where x.cn > 1
```

If you also want the row_number value, add it as a separate column in the select list.

```
select * from (select count()over(partition by .. order by) cn,
                      row_number()over(partition by .. order by) rn
                 from ...) x
where x.cn > 1
```

Updated:
Remove the order by from the count(). Here is an example.

```
create table mytab(id number, name varchar2(100));
insert into mytab values(1,'Ram');
insert into mytab values(1,'Rahim');
insert into mytab values(1,'Reuben');
insert into mytab values(2,'Esther');
insert into mytab values(3,'Veena');
insert into mytab values(3,'Visu');
insert into mytab values(4,'Vishnu');
commit;

select * from mytab;
```

Output:

```
ID NAME 
1 Ram 
1 Rahim 
1 Reuben 
2 Esther 
3 Veena 
3 Visu 
4 Vishnu
```

```
select * 
  from (select id, 
               name,
               count(1) over(partition by id) cn, 
               row_number() over(partition by id order by name) rn 
          from mytab) x
 where x.cn > 1;
```

Output:

```
ID  NAME    CN  RN
1   Rahim   3   1
1   Ram     3   2
1   Reuben  3   3
3   Veena   2   1
3   Visu    2   2
```

Comment: I think count would work fine as well but it is also leaving out 1

Comment: Remove the `ORDER BY` clause from the `COUNT OVER` function, because you want a total count, not a running number. Also it's `COUNT(*)`, not `COUNT()`.

Comment: using count and removing order by in over function did what I need, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with an example on the Employees table in the HR schema.

```
SELECT
    row_number() over (partition by salary order by salary) as serial_no,
    employee_id,
    first_name,
    salary,
    department_id
FROM
    employees
WHERE
    salary IN (
        SELECT
            salary
        FROM
            employees
        GROUP BY
            salary
        HAVING
            COUNT(salary) > 1

    ) ORDER BY salary;
```

See if this fulfills your purpose and kindly provide a feedback.